# Order rows in a sequence and fill gaps for missing rows

Tags: t-sql, sequence, gaps-in-data

I got a problem regarding missing rows in a table that is giving me a headache.

As base data, I have the following table:

```
declare @table table
(
  id1   int,
  id2   int,
  ch    char(1) not null,
  val   int     
)

insert into @table values (1112, 121, 'A', 12)
insert into @table values (1351, 121, 'A', 13)
insert into @table values (1411, 121, 'B', 81)
insert into @table values (1312, 7, 'C', 107)
insert into @table values (1401, 2, 'A', 107)
insert into @table values (1454, 2, 'D', 107)
insert into @table values (1257, 6, 'A', 1)
insert into @table values (1269, 6, 'B', 12)
insert into @table values (1335, 6, 'C', 12)
insert into @table values (1341, 6, 'D', 5)
insert into @table values (1380, 6, 'A', 3)
```

The output should be ordered by id2 and follow a fixed sequence of ch, which should repeat until next id2 begins.

Sequence:

```
'A'
'B'
'C'
'D'
```

If the sequence or the pattern is interrupted, it should fill the missing rows with null, so that i get this result table:

```
id1     id2     ch     val
----------------------------    
1112    121     'A'    12
NULL    121     'B'    NULL
NULL    121     'C'    NULL
NULL    121     'D'    NULL
1351    121     'A'    13
1411    121     'B'    81
NULL    121     'C'    NULL
NULL    121     'D'    NULL
NULL    7       'A'    NULL
NULL    7       'B'    NULL
1312    7       'C'    107
NULL    7       'D'    NULL
1401    2       'A'    107
NULL    2       'B'    NULL
NULL    2       'C'    NULL
1454    2       'D'    107
```

and so on...

What I'm looking for is a way to do this without iterations.

I hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution might be this:

```
declare @table table (  id1   int,  id2   int,  ch    char(1) not null,  val   int     )
insert into @table values (1112, 121, 'A', 12)
    ,(1351, 121, 'A', 13),(1411, 121, 'B', 81),(1312, 7, 'C', 107),(1401, 2, 'A', 107)
    ,(1454, 2, 'D', 107),(1257, 6, 'A', 1),(1269, 6, 'B', 12),(1335, 6, 'C', 12)
    ,(1341, 6, 'D', 5),(1380, 6, 'A', 3)
;with foo as
(select 
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by id2 order by id1) rwn
    ,ascii(isnull(lag(ch,1) over (partition by id2 order by id1),'A'))-ascii('A')  prev
    ,count(*) over (partition by id2,ch) nr
    ,ascii(ch)-ascii('A') cur
from @table

)
,bar as
(
select 
*,case when cur<=prev and rwn>1 then 4 else 0 end + cur-prev step
from foo
)
,foobar as
(
select *,sum(step) over (partition by id2 order by id1 rows unbounded preceding) rownum
from bar
)
,iterations as
(
select id2,max(nr) nr from foo
group by id2
)
,blanks as
(
select
id2,ch chnr,char(ch+ascii('A') )ch,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id2 order by c.nr,ch)-1 rownum,c.nr
from iterations a
inner join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) c(nr)
on c.nr<=a.nr
cross join (values (0),(1),(2),(3)) b(ch)
)
select
b.id1,a.id2,a.ch,b.val
from blanks a
left join foobar b
on a.id2=b.id2 and a.rownum=b.rownum 
order by a.id2,a.rownum
```

I first make the query "foo" which looks at the row number and gets the previous value for ch for each id2.

"bar" then finds how many missing values there are between the rows. For instance If the previous was an A and the current is a c then there are 2. If the previous was an A and the current is an A, then there are 4!

"foobar" then adds the steps, thus numbering the original rows, where they should be in the final output.

"iterations" counts the number of times the "ABCD" rows should appear.

"BLANKS" then is all the final rows, that is for each id2, it outputs all the "ABCD" rows that should be in the final output, and numbers them in rownum

Finally I left join "foobar" with "BLANKS" on id2 and rownum. Thus we get the correct number of rows, and the places where there are values in the original is output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm little confused by your output, try this:

Update

```
   DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      row INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      id1 INT ,
      id2 INT ,
      ch CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
      val INT
    );

 DECLARE @Sequence TABLE ( ch3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL );


 INSERT INTO @Sequence
 VALUES ( 'A' );
 INSERT INTO @Sequence
 VALUES ( 'B' );
 INSERT INTO @Sequence
 VALUES ( 'C' );
 INSERT INTO @Sequence
 VALUES ( 'D' );

 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1112, 121, 'A', 12 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1351, 121, 'A', 13 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1411, 121, 'B', 81 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1312, 7, 'C', 107 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1401, 2, 'A', 107 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1454, 2, 'D', 107 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1257, 6, 'A', 1 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1269, 6, 'B', 12 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1335, 6, 'C', 12 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1341, 6, 'D', 5 );
 INSERT INTO @table
 VALUES ( 1380, 6, 'A', 3 );




 SELECT r.id1 ,
        fin.id2 ,
        ch3 ,
        r.val
 FROM   ( SELECT    *
          FROM      ( SELECT    CASE WHEN r.chd - l.chd = 1 THEN 0
                                     ELSE 1
                                END [gap in sq] ,
                                l.*
                      FROM      ( SELECT    id2 ,
                                            ASCII(ch) chd ,
                                            ch ,
                                            val ,
                                            id1 ,
                                            row
                                  FROM      @table
                                ) AS l
                                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id2 ,
                                                    ASCII(ch) chd ,
                                                    row
                                            FROM    @table
                                          ) AS r ON l.row = r.row - 1
                    ) AS temp ,
                    @Sequence s
          WHERE     temp.[gap in sq] = 1
                    OR ( temp.[gap in sq] = 0
                         AND s.ch3 = temp.ch
                       )
        ) AS fin
        LEFT JOIN @table r ON r.id2 = fin.id2
                              AND r.id1 = fin.id1
                              AND r.ch = fin.ch3
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot! But 1351 and 1411 are in the same sequence. So 1411 should follow right after 1351 at row 6 not row 10

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to add an extra column in your table, that defines which [id2] are part from the same sequence you can try this:

```
declare @table table
(
  id1   int,
  id2   int,
  ch    char(1) not null,
  val   int,
  category  int -- extra column
)

insert into @table values (1112, 121, 'A', 12, 1)
insert into @table values (1351, 121, 'A', 13, 2)
insert into @table values (1411, 121, 'B', 81, 2)
insert into @table values (1312, 7, 'C', 107, 3)
insert into @table values (1401, 2, 'A', 107, 4)
insert into @table values (1454, 2, 'D', 107, 4)
insert into @table values (1257, 6, 'A', 1, 5)
insert into @table values (1269, 6, 'B', 12, 5)
insert into @table values (1335, 6, 'C', 12, 5)
insert into @table values (1341, 6, 'D', 5, 5)
insert into @table values (1380, 6, 'A', 3, 5)


DECLARE @sequence table (seq varchar(1))
INSERT INTO @sequence values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')


SELECT b.id1, a.id2, a.seq, b.val, a.category
INTO #T1
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM  @table
    CROSS JOIN @sequence
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM @table
) B
    ON 1=1
    AND a.id1 = b.id1
    AND a.id2 = b.id2
    AND a.seq = b.ch
    AND a.val = b.val


;WITH rem_duplicates AS (
    SELECT *, dup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by id2, seq, category ORDER BY id1 DESC)
    FROM #T1
) DELETE FROM rem_duplicates WHERE dup > 1


SELECT * FROM #T1 ORDER BY id2 DESC, category ASC, seq ASC

DROP TABLE #T1
```